# How to get folder and file path dynamically in R

Tags: r, path

I have a project folder, name `project`. The structure looks like the bellow one

```
project
    dataset
    output
    scripts
```

Now, I want to `read` file from `dataset` folder and want to `write` file in the `output` folder. All my codes are in the `scripts` folder.

I can do it using hardcode path style, like,

```
df_1 <- read.csv(~project/dataset/test.csv)
df_2 <- write.csv(~project/output/test_output.csv)
```

This (hardcoded) causing problems. If I run the code from another device or if another person wants to run code in his/her device, then they need to change the path manually.

Is there any way to write the code, so people do not need to change the path address manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is customary to launch scripts relative to the path from which the data is accessed.

For instance, you might do something like this in your terminal:

```sh
cd path/to/data
Rscript path/to/script.r
```

This sets the working directory to `path/to/data`, and to access this data inside R you can now simply use relative paths:

```r
df_1 <- read.csv('dataset/test.csv')
write.csv(df_1, 'output/test_output.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But, I want to do anything in my scripts. Because I have to run the code using a bash script. So, I need to get the directory from my code.

Comment: @Opps_0 Can you explain in what way this isn’t answered by my question? The first piece of code I’ve shown launches your R code, and is a valid Bash script.

Comment: Say, I have a bash script contains this code `#!/bin/bash`
`python3 a.py` `Rscript myscript1.r`. Then where should I write `cd path/to/data` in my bash? Sorry, I am new in bash!

Comment: @Opps_0 You can write it in a line just before the `RScript` part. But that doesn’t really solve your issue, it just moves it from R to Bash. Instead, this code shouldn’t be part of your Bash script (or R script) *at all*. The *user* sets the working directory (by running `cd …`) before executing your code.

Comment: Do I have to change this `cd path/to/data` with my folder path?

Comment: Just replace `path/to/data` with the actual path in your case.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Now, if other people want to run the bash script they need to change the path manually (in the bash script only), right?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to open R via your terminal, `Sys.info()` provides data that you can use to your advantage here. `Sys.info()["user"]` provides the ID of the current R user, so you can set working directories at the top of your file like this:

```
if(Sys.info()["user"] == "User 1") {
  setwd("[User 1's directory]")
} else if(Sys.info()["user"] == "User 2") {
  setwd("[User 2's directory]")
}
```

Then, once you've set the working directory to be the same place across users, you can use the same filenames. You can also set full filenames/paths dynamically like this without messing with the working directory (this can be particularly useful when someone is on a PC and another person is on a mac, as the slashes work differently).

Comment: I have to run my code from a bash script.

Comment: I'm not familiar with bash, how does this make this solution not work?

Comment: The code you’ve posted still hard-codes user names. It also doesn’t really do anything useful: it can be replaced by `setwd('~')`. And using `setwd` is also unnecessary — just refer to `~` inside the paths if that’s the aim (though all of these solutions still hard-code the path somewhat).

Comment: It's useful if there are more differences in the filepaths beyond just the home directories

Comment: Honestly? No, it isn’t useful. It *still* hard-codes machine specifics in the code, where this doesn’t belong. It’s the *user’s* responsibility to run the code in the desired location.

Comment: Fair, but not all of us launch R from a terminal! I've been in multiple workplaces where this solution has been used - at least as a workaround

Comment: @ila You absolutely don’t need to launch R scripts from the command line for this to work. If you’re bound to a GUI the conventional way would be to wrap this into a launcher script that accepts the path as an argument, and then launch it by dragging & dropping the folder onto the script (on Windows). An alternative is to use separate config files. These are *solved problems* that all work better than hard-coding stuff in code.